# Solve $\sqrt{\left(a+1\right)^2+b^2}\ge2+a$

Tags: inequality

I stumbled across this inequation and I am stuck at the solution:
$$\tag{$\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$} \sqrt{\left(a+1\right)^2+b^2}\ge2+a$$

It is equal to:
$$
\tag{if a ≥ −2}
=\left(a+1\right)^2+b^2\ge\left(2+a\right)^2\ \ \
$$

$$a \ge (b^2-3)\cdot\frac{1}{2}$$

But I am not able to get rid of the root when $a <-2$:
$$
=\sqrt{\left(a+1\right)^2+b^2}\ge2+a 
$$
In the first part I could just square both sides because both sides were non-negative. But this is not the case if $a <-2$ How could this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $a <-2$, RHS is negative, whereas LHS is always positive. Hence this is always true. Therefore the solution will be

$$b \in \Bbb R , a \in (-\infty,-2)$$

Answer (score 1):

If $a<-2$, then the right hand side is $a+2<0$, but notice that the left hand side is always nonnegative.

Hence $a<-2$ would satisfy the inequality regardless of the values of $b$.

Comment: Oh wow yeah that is makes sense! Thank you. Can't believe I did not see this one.